# Connecting two routers to one modem to create better security for each network

Tags: router, security, ethernet, modem

Our business has a router connected to a modem in Building A. From here, Ethernet runs throughout Building A, and then to Building B.

We have a tenant in a section of Building B that wants to have their own router from the modem so that they have their own separated network and have that much more security from our network. Connecting their router directly to the modem that resides in Building A would require running another ethernet between the buildings.

The tenant says that we can just attach their own router to the ethernet already coming from Building A (and already in Building B), but then wouldn't their network not be separated from ours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ethernet cable going to building B is coming from your router, then yes, if the tenant connects their router, you would have access to all their unencrypted upstream traffic. More importantly, they would have access to any shares or devices on your network that is not secured in some fashion.

If you were to disconnect the ethernet cable going to building B from your router and plug it directly into the modem so that the tenant could then hook up the router, then each of you would be on your own private networks. However, how would all your devices in building B now attach to your network if you give up the ethernet cable in this fashion.

The most secure solution is to run a new ethernet cable from the modem to their router to protect both networks. With that said, since you control the modem, it is always possible for you to insert a device that enables you to do man-in-the-middle attacks on your tenant if you were devious ... but that should be a security concern of your tenant.